# Public certificate, private key asymmetricsecurity element

Tags: wcf, security

My wsdl says Asymmetric Binding. Initiator Token and Receipienct TokenHow can I generate a binary security token for both client and server. Can I implement with kind of security with only one private key. 
. 
Here is the wsdl

```
            <sp:AsymmetricBinding>
    <wsp:Policy>
        <wsp:ExactlyOne><wsp:All><sp:InitiatorToken><wsp:Policy><wsp:ExactlyOne>
<wsp:All><sp:X509Token><wsp:Policy>
<wsp:ExactlyOne><wsp:All><sp:WssX509V3Token11/></wsp:All>
                    </wsp:ExactlyOne>
                </wsp:Policy></sp:X509Token></wsp:All>
                </wsp:ExactlyOne></wsp:Policy></sp:InitiatorToken>
                <sp:RecipientToken><wsp:Policy><wsp:ExactlyOne><wsp:All><sp:X509Token><wsp:Policy><wsp:ExactlyOne><wsp:All>
                <sp:WssX509V3Token11/>
                </wsp:All>
                </wsp:ExactlyOne>
                </wsp:Policy>
                </sp:X509Token>
                </wsp:All>
            </wsp:ExactlyOne>
                </wsp:Policy></sp:RecipientToken>
                <sp:AlgorithmSuite><wsp:Policy><wsp:ExactlyOne><wsp:All><sp:TripleDesRsa15/></wsp:All></wsp:ExactlyOne></wsp:Policy>
                </sp:AlgorithmSuite>
                </wsp:All></wsp:ExactlyOne
                ></wsp:Policy>
            </sp:AsymmetricBinding>
```

In case I make a custom binding with security element like this .

```
 `var sec = `(AsymmetricSecurityBindingElement)SecurityBindingElement.CreateMutualCertificateBindingElement(MessageSecurityVersion.WSSecurity10WSTrust13WSSecureConversation13WSSecurityPolicy12BasicSecurityProfile10);
```

I was able to genrte Username token with none. This was the security element

```
var security = TransportSecurityBindingElement.CreateUserNameOverTransportBindingElement();
```

The Sample soap request uses these terms to describe the binary security tokens

....(eMedNY signed user MLS cert).....
   .....( eMedNY MLS web-service end-point public cert).........
...nonce,.
I have the private key for the former. But does the server one need a private key?.. It is a public certificate. What should be the security element. Do I need two security elements. One for the binary security token and one for usernametoken.?

Thank u

Comment: Hi, Doesnt anyone have an answer.. This stuff is literally giving me nightmares

Comment: Did you have any luck with this? I'm starting a similar project and would love some direction, pointers and tips...

Comment: @IsaacKleinman: Hi, I was able to get a successful request which matches the outgoing request 100%. But not successful in getting a response.:( Mine needed encryption, signature and nonce and lot more. i had to modify the message at some point using a messageencoder either to add a nonce or others. The service didn't like this modification and kept telling me that the hash value has been modified or hash values do not match.  It took me lot of time and learning for matching the outgoing and expected soap. But couldn't waste another month for figuring out why hash doesn't match. All the best.

Comment: @IsaacKleinman: I would be glad to help if you need any

Comment: Thanks for the offer; that would be greatly appreciated. I'm actually also working with `emedny`, so I guess I'll be facing the exact same issues you did. I'm a total n00b to the domain, so perhaps you can clarify a few things for me. 1) Does fact that I have to use SOAP with Attachments mean that WCF won't help me out here? (Is the proxy generated by `svcutil` of any value to me?) 2) What are the .NET utilities I might use to help me compose and read the SOAP messages?

Comment: I am by no means a master in this. This was my first wcf application. Had to learn wcf to do this.. lol!! Yes, svcutils's proxy helped. My email: schalla_27@yahoo.com. I dont what you mean by soap with attachments. If you look at emedney's user guide, the soap needs signature, encyption, usernametoken with nonce. Noce is not supported by wcf. So went and did some custom stuff to generate a nonce. I didn't use any extra .net utilities.. just simple proxy client. Again I was successful in getting a 100% compliant request. But couldn't get a valid 271 response from them. Feel free to email me

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?